# How to collect SF reverse proxy logs on-prem

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I have 3-node on-prem cluster. Now i want to collect and analyze reverse proxy logs (and other system service fabric logs). I google and found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverse-proxy-diagnostics) and it says

> Refer to [Collect reverse proxy events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-aggregation-wad#log-collection-configurations) to enable collecting events from
>   these channels in local and Azure Service Fabric clusters.

But that link describes how to enable, configure and collect reverse proxy logs for clusters in Azure. And I don't understand how to do it on-prem.
Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric Events are just ETW events, you have the option to use the Builtin mechanism to collect and forward these events to a Monitoring Application like Windows Azure Diagnostics, or you can build your own.

If you decide to follow the approach in the documents, it will work on azure or On premises, the only caveat is that On-Premises it will send the logs to Azure, but it will work the same way.

On Premises, another way is build you own collector using [EventFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-aggregation-eventflow), you can configure EventFlow to collect the ReverseProxy ETW events and then forward these to ELK or any other monitoring platform.